# Product Qty Dropdown in Cart Page - Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am developing a shopping cart in Opencart 2.x.

Everything was going smooth but i am stuck at one place where i need a dropdown in `cart.tpl` instead of showing quantity in input box with update cart button.

I have looked into Controller of `cart.php` but not able to figure out where to get quantity.

Code  looked into is as below:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    'cart_id'   => $product['cart_id'],
    'thumb'     => $image,
    'name'      => $product['name'],
    'model'     => $product['model'],
}
```

I tried adding quantity here but not able to get on cart.tpl.

Then i decided to check cart `add()` function and get quantity there as below:

```
public function add() {
  $this->load->model('catalog/product');
  $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
  $data['qty'] = sprintf($product_info['quantity']);
  // I added this data line
}
```

but even then on doing `echo $qty` on cart.tpl gives nothing.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open system\library\cart\cart.php and find following lines of code:

```
$product_data[] = array(
                'cart_id'         => $cart['cart_id'],
                'product_id'      => $product_query->row['product_id'],
```

Below these lines of code add following line:

```
'product_quantity'           => $product_query->row['quantity'],
```

Second open controller catalog\controller\checkout\cart.php and find following lines of code:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                'cart_id'   => $product['cart_id'],
```

Below these lines of codes add following line:

```
'product_quantity'=>$product['product_quantity'],
```

At last find following lines of code at catalog/view/theme/YOUR_ACTIVATED_THEME/template/checkout/cart.tpl

```
<td class="text-left">
                  <div class="input-group btn-block" style="max-width: 200px;">
                      <input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>]"
                             value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" size="1" class="form-control"/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_update; ?>"
                        class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>"
                        class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>');"><i
                            class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
                </span></div>
              </td>
```

Replace with the following code:

```
<!--Changes done-->
              <td class="text-left">
                  <div class="input-group btn-block" style="max-width: 200px;">
                      <select name="quantity[<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>]"
                              onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                          <?php for($cp=1; $cp<=$product['product_quantity']; $cp++){ ?>
                          <option
                          <?php if($product['quantity']==$cp){ echo "selected"; } ?>
                          value="<?php echo $cp; ?>"><?php echo $cp; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                      </select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>"
            class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>');"><i
                class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
    </span>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <!--End of Changes done-->
```

You can download changed files from following links and see the changes as well as see demo in images:
https://webocreation.com/blog/dropdown-quantity-product-cart-page-opencart-2-2